# Can we pass taskId to Case creation url

Tags: apex, visualforce

There is dialer Visualforce page, when i get a call i will get logcall
id(TaskId). So I have a TaskId. There is a Link called as Add_Case If i wanted to create a case can i pass that TaskId to case creation page using url.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are storing the TaskId in your controller, you can redirect the user to case creation page and pass the parameters in the url as:

`return new PageReference( '/apex/your_Page_name?taskId=' + taskId );`

and you can then retrieve the task Id in the case creation page controller as

`String taskId = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get( 'taskId' );`

Comment: i am using "Window.open('/005/e')" for creating a case in javascript. When i click on Add_case() it is calling javascript function. It is opening case standard page for creation of Case. Then how can i get the newly created Case Id.

Comment: Could you please clarify your requirement more? May be screenshots of what you are trying / tried so far or steps?

Comment: When user clicks on LeadCreation link, it will goto standard salesforce lead creation page(not custom form page). Then user tries to save the record, then the page needs to return id to the controller after record creation.